# Найти максимальное и минимальное значения в файле

Tags: c#, winforms, строки

Пытаюсь реализовать в Windows Forms нахождение максимального и минимального числа в файле. В файле присутствуют как числа так и слова. Число находит, но точно не максимальное. В чем ошибка?

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            FileStream stream1 = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            {
                byte[] array = new byte[stream1.Length];
                stream1.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
                string textFromFile = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
                string[] words = textFromFile.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                string im = words.Count().ToString();
                int max = im.Max();
                richTextBox1.AppendText(max.ToString());
```

Comment: `string im = words.Count().ToString();` - это зачем?

Comment: @Igor Чтобы преобразовать string в int

Comment: `string im = words.Count().ToString();
   int max = im.Max();` так оно у вас не как не связано с числами в файле

Comment: у вас числа значения в файле разделяются пробелами ?

Comment: @Клешня Какой `string` в какой `int`?

Comment: @OXYGEN Да, пробелами

Comment: Но судя по вашему коду вы не ищите не мин не мах в тексте а получаете просто число которое равно кол-ву размера массива `string[] words`

Comment: скиньте пример текста в котором вы ищите min-max

Comment: @OXYGEN
`1199821 119982 System.Random 1116040 404655 928284 1739503 495362 49536 System.Random 2085769 95405 954 Save...`

Comment: @Igor String "words" преобразовываю в int "max", чтобы использовать операцию Max()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не понимаете как работает `.Count()` вот здесь:
    string im = words.Count().ToString();
    int max = im.Max();

Тут вы берете `words`, считаете сколько в нем элементов (скажем в массиве после разбития через `.Split()` у вас 10 значений, вот 10 вы и получаете), дальше вы преобразовываете это число в строку (а строка это по сути массив из символов) и дальше вы из этого "массива символов" берете максимальное.

Что бы ваш код работал, вам надо достать от туда только числа, преобразовать их в правильный формат (`int`) и уже потом из получившейся коллекции доставать минимальное и максимальное.

---

Как вариант на LINQ:

```
var fileText = "1199821 119982 System.Random 1116040 404655 928284 1739503 495362 49536 System.Random 2085769 95405 954 Save";
var result = fileText.Split().Select(x => new { isNum = int.TryParse(x, out int value), value }).Where(x=> x.isNum).Select(x=> x.value);
Console.WriteLine($"Min: {result.Min()} Max: {result.Max()}");
```

Пояснения:

- `fileText` - это то, что у нас прочиталось из файла, я просто взял строку из комментария.
- `.Split()` - разбиваем строку по пробелу.
- `.Select(x => new { isNum = int.TryParse(x, out int value), value })` - преобразуем каждое значение в анонимный тип, который будет содержать 2 значения:

  1. `bool isNum` - метод `TryParse()` возвращает `true` если ему удалось преобразовать в число и `false` если нет.
  2. `int value` - метод `TryParse()` через `out` вернет либо `default`(0), если значение не удалось преобразовать, либо само преобразованное число.
- `.Where(x=> x.isNum)` - берем только то, что удалось преобразовать.
- `.Select(x=> x.value)` - ну и берем только числа, ибо `bool` значения нам дальше не понадобятся.

Остается взять минимальное и максимальное. Для этого не поверите, но тоже есть свои методы - `Min()` и соответственно `Max()`, нам остается просто их вызвать, что я и делаю в данной строке: `Console.WriteLine($"Min: {result.Min()} Max: {result.Max()}");`

Результат: `Min: 954 Max: 2085769`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так это примерно должно быть

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int min = -1, max = -1;
        string filePath;
        using (var opf = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                filePath = opf.FileName;
            else
                return;
        }


        var fileData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);


        foreach (var data in fileData)
        {
            var tmp = data.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var cheRegex = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");

            foreach (var t in tmp)
                if (cheRegex.IsMatch(t))
                {
                    var tint = Convert.ToInt32(t);
                    if (min == -1 && max == -1)
                    {
                        max = tint;
                        min = tint;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (tint > max)
                            max = tint;
                        if (tint < min)
                            min = tint;
                    }
                }

            label1.Text = string.Format("min={0} max={1}", min, max); // куда выводить результат
        }
    }
```